# integrate react semantic ui checkbox with redux form

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, redux-form

I want to add a  in a react semantic UI 
but it cannot send the checked value to server even after I name Checkbox like this:

```
<Form.Field
  label="The question is new to the intent library"
  name="newType"
  control={Field}
  component={Checkbox}
/>
```

This component is inside a form like this:

```
<Form>
 <Form.Field
  label="Rating"
  control={Field}
  name="rate"
  component={Rating}
  ...
 />
 <That checkbox ... />
 <Form.Field
  label="Comment"
  control={Field}
  name="comment"
  component="textarea"
 />
</Form>
```

Supposed action should carry the checked value in payload, similar to how rating and comment are carried.

I am stuck in this for half a day
Please help me if you notice something. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved by using the following code

```
<Form.Field 
 control={Field}
 label="The question is new to the intent library"
 name="newType"
 component="input"
 type="checkbox"
/>
```